# Why post-merge hook not working with cronjob?

Tags: git, cron

I am a bit stuck and any help will appreciated. I am using cronjob on my staging server to have up-to-date repo with compiled assets. This is my cronjob command I am using:

```
* * * * * cd ~/public_html/ && git reset --hard && git pull
```

then in .git/hooks/post-merge I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sh compile.sh
```

permissions:

```
7494392 -rwxr-xr-x 1 admin admin   34 Jan 30 17:44 post-merge
```

finally my compile.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd assets && gulp dev
```

This hook is executed when I am doing it manually from ssh command line, but not via cron job. Can anyone point me in right direction?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you logging the output of this cron job anywhere? That's step 1. You can log the stdout and stderr of the cron job with `(cd ~/public_html/ && git reset --hard && git pull) >> ~/path/to/logfile.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @NickODell have added logging to see what happens there. Will do some tests and let you know.

Comment: Just normal git output in that logfile no errors. I have changed post-merge content with:

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd assets && /usr/local/bin/gulp dev`

and it is working now. I don't know why it is failing using sh command.